# jQuery AJAX post to php probleme

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

when echo the variable on php it works , but for insert it to database it doesn't ,  what is the probleme I didn't see any issue on the code , thanks for help

**HTML/JQUERY**

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="name" ><br/> 
    <input type="text" id="age" ><br/> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form> 
<div id="result"></div>

   <script> 

   $(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val(); 
        var age = $('#age').val();

        $.ajax({
        url: 'validate.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {postname:name, postage:age},
        success: function(res) {
            $("#result").append(res);
        } 
    });
    });
}); 
   </script>
```

**php**

```
<?php 

    include 'mysqldb.php';


    $name = $_POST['postname']; 
    $age =  $_POST['postage']; 


    $sql = "insert into uss (first, last) values('".$name."','".$age."')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo $result ;

    ?>
```

**error on console**

```
POST http://localhost/validate.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
        send @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
        ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
        (anonymous) @ jquery.PHP:26
        dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
        q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
```

**mysqldb.php**   this is the php file to connect to the database

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password' , 'database');

if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());

}

?>
```

Comment: The query is well built.
The variables there are well encapsulated. Try use mysqli in the following way:
`$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo $result ; } `

Comment: hello , nope sorry it doesn't make any change

Comment: do you have `$conn` defined?

Comment: `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}`

Comment: <?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password' , 'database');

if (!$conn) {
 
 die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
 
}

?>

Comment: of course wouldn't work, $conn needs to be mysqli as well

Comment: are you meaning to enter age into the "last" (assuming last name) field? you may be experiencing some data_type errors trying to insert.

Comment: thanks for respond guys ,  @tiagoperes  yes when i  put mysqli_connect , in place of  mysql_connect ,  it work

Comment: great it could help

Comment: @tiagoperes  I edit the post for your solution be more clear , if you want write it like an answer not comment  , maybe it could help someone else , thanks

Comment: PLEASE NOTE that if $age would contain "age');drop table uss;#" this would result in your entire table 'uss' being dropped from the database! Check for code injections!!

Comment: @patrick i'll fix it  thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is "well" built.

The variables there are well encapsulated.

There's some security issues that you can fix by preventing against cross site scripting (XSS) and SQL injection. This is done at the query level.
There's lots of threads in Stack explaining how to do that.

Try and use mysqli in the following way:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "your query here";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo $result ;
} `
```

Thank you for telling me to write the suggestion in an answer.

Thank you also for accepting as the right answer, that showed a lot of consideration from your side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see the exact error:

```
<?php
try
{

      $conn = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
      $sql = "insert into uss (first, last) values('".$name."','".$age."')";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
catch(PDOException  $e ){
       echo "Error: ".$e;
       }
   .....//
```